# setting Position of Loading-indicator

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css, loading

I defined a Loading-Indicator, and have some problem with the position. My problem is
 positioning the loading indicator when its seen through different machines with different 
 resolution or screen size. how can i fix it!

here is my code:

```
<body class="loadPage">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
  </asp:ScriptManager>

  <div id="loadingLogo">
     <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="Images/Logo.png" />
     <hr class="line"/>
  </div>

  <div id="loadingIndicator" >
     <syncfusion:WaitingPopup ID="WaitingPopup1" runat="server" CloseTimeOut="2000"    
                 ClientObjectID="Popup1" PositionParent="Screen"
                 Width="250px" Height="50px" Alignment="MiddleRight"  
                 InitiallyShown="True" DisableOnShowElementID="loadingIndicator">
     </syncfusion:WaitingPopup>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: if the query is related Syncfusion means better you can tag it with "Syncfusion". May be they will respond here.

Answer (score 0):

You do not write where you want it positioned, but i would recommend using position: absolute; or position: fixed; See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

If you want it center the css could be something like

```
#loadingIndicator {
position: absolute;
width: 200px;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -100px;
top: 10px;
}
```

Margin-left should be minus half the width of your loadginIndicator, to center it.

Comment: sorry i forget to write it. it should be displayed under the Line (<hr>) on the right-side

Comment: Okay is your <hr> full width of your site? If it is then drop left and margin-left and use right: 0px; in my css example, and adjust top to fit

Comment: thanx for your help but i found the solution for my problem